# Algorithmic, put curled bracket over states

Tags: algorithmic

I am using the algorithm package and I want to but brackets over a set of lines, because it will be repeated for some cases..

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}
 \caption{my algorithm}
 \begin{algorithmic}
 \STATE \(value = 9\)  **
 \IF{lalla}
 \ENDIF
 \ELSE *
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

So I want a curled bracket on the right of the lines from ** to * and then to add a comment there, is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".